# Get firebase.database on component?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, components

I am trying to access the firebase database on a child component but the app is throwing a Firebase error no App. I can’t re-initialise the app on the component or I will create a duplicate app.
I just want to define a variable that relates to the database:

```
import Firebase from "firebase";
var usersRef = Firebase.database().ref('users')
```

Comment: Have you looked into using [Vuefire](https://github.com/vuejs/vuefire)?

Comment: Where are you initializing your firebase app? what is the error?

Comment: Hi @Bert. Yes, I am using Vuefire. Gabriel I am initialising my firebase app from the main.js.

    const config = {
        apiKey: "*************",
        authDomain: "********.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://******.firebaseio.com",
      };

    Firebase.initializeApp(config);
    Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
 new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    components: { App },
    template: '<App/>'
  })
    })

Comment: the error is when i try to address a ref on on my database. "variable is not defined"  or, if I re initialise the firebase app on the component, "duplicated app".